# Bot User State property not able to read when specified in .lg file (Generated using Bot Framework Composer)

Tags: botframework

I have create a User State property in the code using the following code snippet:

```
userProfileProperty = UserState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
```

As can be seen above I am using a custom class object as the preoprty value i.e. UserProfile class, and this class holds various class properties as shown:

```
public class UserProfile
    {
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }

        public string UserAlias { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Now when I am trying to access the same property in a AdaptiveDialog flow by mentioning it in .lg file as shown below:

```
# bfdprompt-254582()
- what is your name

# bfdactivity-998627()
- Your name is @{user.name}

# bfdactivity-709726()
- Starting the First Dialog

# bfdactivity-496995()
- Test custom value is @{user.userprofile.useremail}
```

I am getting the following exception:

[image]

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **property name directly** like below as long as you are sending the model **UserProfile** to the template engine

```cs
# bfdactivity-496995()
- Test custom value is @{useremail}
```

Take a look at this working example for more details:

```cs
  private class UserLanguagePreference
        {
            public string OldLanguage { get; set; }
            public string NewLanguage { get; set; }
        }
```

We are fetching the response from the .lg file using the template engine like below:

```cs
 UserLanguagePreference userLanguagePreference = new UserLanguagePreference
                    {
                        OldLanguage = _state.UserInfoState.LanguagePreference,
                        NewLanguage = PayloadsLanguageEnum.GetValueFromCode(payload).Name
                    };

 await sc.Context.SendActivityAsync(_templateEngine.GenerateActivityForLocale("UpdateLanguagePreference", userLanguagePreference));
```

The .lg file has the following:

```cs
# UpdateLanguagePreference
- Language preference changed from : @{OldLanguage} to @{NewLanguage}
```